# how to clone a solidbrush in GDI+ C++

Tags: c++, gdi+, clone

I am using gdi+ and c++.
I have a question about SolidBrush.
How To clone a SolidBrush?

```
SolidBrush* oldBrush xxx;
Brush* newBrush = oldBrush->Clone();
```

I found newBrush is a Brush Object.
Which mean if I use `dynamic_cast<SolidBrush>(newBursh)`, I will always get NULL.

I read the .h file of gdi+ SolidBrush seems used Brush's virtual Clone method, it do not override it!

Why?

Thanks for solutions, but I still have a question? why SolidBrush do not implement Clone Method?

Answer (score 1):

`Brush` can do everything `SolidBrush` can. `SolidBrush` is just a convenient way to create a `Brush` with a solid color.

Here's an example derived from [this example at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536273(VS.85).aspx):

```
SolidBrush solidBrush(Color(255,255,0,0));
Brush *clone = solidBrush.Clone();
```

You can then just go ahead and use `clone` like any other brush and it'll behave exactly like `solidBrush`.

Answer (score 0):

> why SolidBrush do not implement Clone Method?

`SolidBrush` inherits the `clone` method from Brush.  Implementing it again in `SolidBrush` would be redundant.

Comment: Actually I think clone method should invoke its own construct, so it must be overrided. Otherwise how can it create a object of its own type?

Comment: The `SolidBrush` class creates exactly the same type of GDI+ object as the `Brush` class.  These classes are simply C++ wrappers over C APIs, and `Brush::Clone` just calls `::GdipCloneBrush`, and wraps the result in a new `Brush` object (NOT a `SolidBrush` object).  The code is right there in `GdiPlusBrush.h`, you should look at it.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the color property of the SolidBrush and it will be cloned. It's a SolidBrush, therefore, only important thing is color anyway.

Something like this should work:

`Brush* newBrush = new Brush(oldBrush->Color);`

Comment: Brush is virtual and cannot be instantiated